# "I am plying violin since I was 5 years old" is it correct sentence grammatically?

Tags: tense, sentence-structure, clauses, sequence-of-tenses

I have confusion with a sentence. Is there anybody who can help me? The sentence is given below.
**I am plying violin since I was 5 years old** -is it correct sentence grammatically? 
If it is correct then what type of clause this would be- **since I was 5 years old**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The correct grammar

> I have been playing violin since I was 5 years old.

This assumes that the speaker started playing violin at 5 years old and has been playing up to now, continuously.

### The reason

We use `has/have been playing` (present perfect progressive) and not `(be) playing` (present continuous) because `(be) playing` describes "now" only.

`has/have been playing` describes a time period that started in the past and has continued up to "now" and includes "now". This is the case in the sentence in question, based on indicated assumption.

### Type of clause?

`since I was 5 years old` is an adverbial clause, because it describes "when" and points to the verb `have been playing`

Comment: Google Books Ngram Viewer indicates that the phrase *playing **the** violin* is about six times more popular than *playing violin*. I'm not sure whether this represents an Atlantic divide.

Comment: @RonaldSole "I love this place ever since you brought me here" is it correct sentence? Can you please help me?

Comment: @Omar No. Needs present perfect: *I have loved this .......*  (a past action that continues to affect the present)

Comment: @RonaldSole Thank you for your reply! But I found this in "500 days of summer" film where Summer said to Tom, "I loved this place ever since you brought me here". She used past indefinite only. If you are a native would you mind to explain this? I'm trying to be confident in English, Please!

Comment: @Omar The use of the *simple past* in instances like these is a common error. I hear it all the time from BBC  journalists and it makes me shudder. Very often, however, someone might say: *I've loved....* and it might sound like *I loved.....* if the person is speaking quickly or indistinctly.

Comment: @RonaldSole  Ah! Now I have got it. Thank you very much!